# Error 5080: Form Transaction Registration failed

Tags: opayo

I'm getting this generic error whenever I redirect to the payment gateway. I have two SagePay customer accounts available - I can make a test payment using the first account's credentials just fine, but I'm getting 5080 with the second one.

They are both sending the same raw crypt string except for VendorTxCode, Amount, and Description.

```
VendorTxCode=111_7_10_2&Amount=1.00&Currency=GBP&Description=OnlinePayment:WebPaymentID:2&SuccessURL=http://localhost:50186/Payment/ProcessRedirectResponse?TokenID=5&StepID=12&FailureURL=http://localhost:50186/Payment/ProcessRedirectResponse?TokenID=5&StepID=12&CustomerName=_Test&BillingSurname=_Test&BillingFirstnames=Tester&BillingAddress1=Address&BillingCity=City&BillingPostCode=PostCode&BillingCountry=GB&DeliverySurname=_Test&DeliveryFirstnames=Tester&DeliveryAddress1=Address&DeliveryCity=City&DeliveryPostCode=PostCode&DeliveryCountry=GB
```

My first thought is that I may have the wrong encryption password, but I copied the Vendor Name and Encryption Password directly from MySagePay Test.

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: You probably need to URL encode the success and failure addresses as they have `&` in them.

Comment: I can confirm that the raw string is URL encoded before being AES encrypted. Also tested without any query strings and got the same error.

Comment: are you using the correct encryption string for that account?

Comment: Just for other people with this error, I found I got this because my VendorTxCode was not unique per order.  I was using an auto-incremented field in my orders table for the VendorTxCode, I'd made a load of test transactions, then deleted the test orders before going live, then when live I started getting this error. It turned out to be because it was using VendorTxCode values from the id field that I'd used during testing.  This was a pain to debug as the error just started occurring even though no code had changed.

Answer (score 1):

Your string looks fine. Make sure the VendorTxCode is unique.

Check the encryption password corresponds with the correct vendorname and ensure you are pointing to Test:

https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp

Answer (score 1):

I was geting this and it turns out that i was my sagePay account was set to LIVE and i was trying to access the TEST sagePay.

If your account is set to live you can not access the TEST SagePay environment.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Billing country and delivery country was wrong . Always use two digit code of countries like US for (United States Of America) AE for (United Arab Emirates) etc